# Is the map $T(u, v)=(A(u, v), v)$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:\mathbb R^{m+n}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a linear surjective map and let $T:\mathbb R^{n+m}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ be the linear map given by $$T(u, v)=(A(u, v), v).$$ Is it true that $T$ is also surjective?

This question arose from the **local submersion form theorem** where the map $T$ and $A$ are differentials from given maps.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes I tried the usual trick for proving a map is surjective, that is I take $(z, w)\in \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ and I suppose there exists $(z^{'}, w^{'})\in \mathbb R^{m+n}$ such that $T(z^{'}, w^{'})=(z, w)$, but that didn't work out, I guess I'll have to use the linearity for showing this..

Comment: Do you know when is a map surjective?

Comment: No I don't have this information, but I found a condition: For $(z, w)\in \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ there exists $(z^{'}, w^{'})\in\mathbb R^{n+m}$ such that $T(z^{'}, w^{'})=(z, w)$ if and only if $(z_1-z^{'}, z_2-w^{'})\in\textrm{ker}(A)$ where $z=A(z_1, z_2)$..but that is not what I wanted, that was meant to be surjective always =(

Comment: Are you sure you don't know the definition of a surjective function? You must have learned it!

Comment: Of course I know it...

Comment: So, what happens when you try to prove that $T$ is surjective? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: What I tried: Let $(z, w)\in\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m\Rightarrow z=A(z_1, z_2)$ for some $(z_1, z_2)\in\mathbb R^{n+m}$. I want to find $(z^{'}, w^{'})\in \mathbb R^{n+m}$ such that $(z, w)=T(z^{'}, w^{'})=(A(z^{'}, w^{'}), w^{'})=(A(z_1, z_2), w)$ what implies I must take $w^{'}=w$ and I should have $A(z^{'}, w^{'})=A(z_1, z_2)$ but I can only get this if $(z_1-z^{'}, z_2-w^{'})\in \textrm{ker}(A)$ and then?.

Comment: Do not complicate things. Just use the definition: let $(z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$. You have to find $(z',w')\in\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ such that $T(z',w')=(A(z',w'),w')=(z,w)$. Now the question is: do you think that this is possible?

Comment: Well, I guess that is not possible =(

Comment: this problem arose from the local submersion form theorem where I have a map $f:\mathbb R^{n+m}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ such that $df_{(\xi, \eta)}:\mathbb R^{n+m}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is surjective and I defined a map $F:\mathbb R^{n+m}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ such that $dF_{(\xi, \eta)}(u, v)=(df_{\xi}(u, v), v)$ and this should be and isomorphism (hence it should be surjective)..My problem was the abstraction of this and I don't have additional data on that theorem to get to that conclusion so the problem I stated should be analogous to this I told you about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. There is the following counter example:

Suppose $n = m = 1$ and $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $A(u, v) = v$. Then $T(u, v) = (A(u, v), v) = (v, v)$. So $T$ is not surjective as for example $(0, 1) \neq T(u, v)$ for every $(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$